# How can I create a new column for month and year from datetime and logically compare date time in R

Tags: r, date

Question 1:
I have a data whose date variable is in this format:

```
$ purchase_date: Factor w/ 525 levels "01APR2012:00:00:00"
```

How can I  create a new column for the year and a new column for month.

Question 2:

```
data2$mydate <- data2$purchase_date
    as.Date(data2$mydate, format = "%d%B%Y") 

    data2$Fyear<-ifelse(data2$mydate>="2011-08-01" & data2$mydate<"2012-08-31",2012,ifelse(data2$mydate>="2012-08-01" & data2$mydate<"2013-08-01",2013,ifelse(data2$mydate<"2011-08-01",2011,2014)))

> class(data2$mydate)
[1] "factor"
> typeof(data2$mydate)
[1] "integer"

Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(data2$mydate, "2011-08-01") :
  ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(data2$mydate, "2012-08-31") :
  ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

How can I compare the date logically?

Thanks very much!

Comment: (1) What do you think `and` does? Try `&`. (2) Comparing character strings will likely cause incorrect results. And in the second comparison you don't use any quotes at all.  Syntax errors are one of your main concerns.  Please provide a reproducible example and the desired result so people can try to help.

Comment: still not work.

Comment: & you need to quote your dates and convert them to date/datetime; R doesn't know what to do with `12AUG2012`. See `?as.Date`, `?as.POSIXct` and for formatting strings `?strptime`.

Comment: `as.Date("18MAY2013:00:00:00", "%d%B%Y")` - does that help?  Now you can make logical comparisons with other dates.

Comment: It helps. Thank you! This is my first question. I have tried to make this question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("18MAY2013:00:00:00","19MAY2013:00:00:00"))
df$year <- format(as.Date(df$date,"%d%B%Y"),"%Y")
df$month <- format(as.Date(df$date,"%d%B%Y"),"%m")

                date year month
1 18MAY2013:00:00:00 2013    05
2 19MAY2013:00:00:00 2013    05
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lubridate, and convert into a date first.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(date=c("18MAY2013:00:00:00","23MAY2017:00:00:00"))

df2 <- df %>%
     mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d%B%Y:%H:%M:%S"),
            month = month(date),
            year = year(date))

> df2
        date month year
1 2013-05-18     5 2013
2 2017-05-23     5 2017
```

Comment: it says: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Ah sorry - also need to load package `library(dplyr)` .. I'll edit answer